# java.lang.IllegalStateException не могу разобраться

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Не могу понять в чем проблема ошибки

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss (FragmentManager.java:1842)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManager.java:1860)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal (BackStackRecord.java:650)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit (BackStackRecord.java:609)
  at com.robin.vitalij.tanksapi.Retrofit.fragment_adapter.Fragment_adapter_cvodka$SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem (Fragment_adapter_cvodka.java:244)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:101)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem (ViewPager.java:1034)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1248)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1116)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run (ViewPager.java:273)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:803)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:603)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:572)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1265)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1081)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Ссылается на строку `fragmentTransaction7.commit();`

```
Fragment_ranked_battles fragment_ranked_battles = new Fragment_ranked_battles();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction7;
                fragmentTransaction7 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle7 = new Bundle();
                if(vibor == true)
                    bundle7.putInt("Player", 1);
                else
                    bundle7.putInt("Player", 2);
                fragment_ranked_battles.setArguments(bundle7);
                fragmentTransaction7.commit();
                return fragment_ranked_battles;
```

сам фрагмент

```
public class Fragment_adapter_cvodka extends Fragment {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private String[] adapter_cvodka_dost;



private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private Player player;
private boolean vibor;

private AdView mAdView;

private SharedPreferences sPref;

public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_DATE = "DATE";

private boolean isVibor;

private Date date_time;
private Date date;

//Рекламный блок
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adapter_cvodka, container, false);

    sPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            APP_PREFERENCES, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    sPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long OBNOVLENIE = sPref.getLong(APP_PREFERENCES_DATE, 0);

    date_time = new Date();
    date = date_time;


    MobileAds.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            getResources().getString(R.string.admod_id));

    mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (!InternetConnection.isOnline(getActivity()) ||  OBNOVLENIE > date.getTime()) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isVibor = false;
    }
    else {
        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.admod_id));

        // Create the InterstitialAd_ad and set the adUnitId.
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admod_itteractive));

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                InterstitialAd_ad.startGame(mInterstitialAd);
            }
        });

        InterstitialAd_ad.startGame(mInterstitialAd);

        isVibor = true;

        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    adapter_cvodka_dost = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adapter_cvodka_dost);


    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        vibor = bundle.getBoolean("Player_clan");
        if(vibor == true)
            player = ((LocationTanki) getActivity().getApplication()).getPlayer2();
        else
        {
            player = ((LocationTanki) getActivity().getApplication()).getPlayer_find();
        }

    }
    else
        player = null;


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(isVibor == true) {  //реклама

                Date date = new Date();

                if(date_time.getTime() <= date.getTime() ) {

                    InterstitialAd_ad.showInterstitial(mInterstitialAd);



                    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
                    instance.setTime(date);
                    instance.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);// прибавляем 1 к установленной дате
                    date_time = instance.getTime(); // получаем измененную дату

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

    if(player.getChet() == 1)
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(player.getPersonaly_dannie().getNickname());
    else
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.Cvodka));


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setSelected(true);

    return view;
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public int getItemPosition (Object object) { return POSITION_NONE; }

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                Fragment_cvodka fragment_cvodka = new Fragment_cvodka();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Log.e("TETETETETET", Boolean.toString(vibor));
                bundle.putBoolean("Player", vibor);
                fragment_cvodka.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                return fragment_cvodka;

            case 1:
                Fragment_statistika fragment_statistika = new Fragment_statistika();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3;
                fragmentTransaction3 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
                if(vibor == true)
                    bundle3.putInt("Player", 1);
                else
                    bundle3.putInt("Player", 2);
                fragment_statistika.setArguments(bundle3);
                fragmentTransaction3.commit();
                return fragment_statistika;

            case 2:
                Fragment_ranked_battles fragment_ranked_battles = new Fragment_ranked_battles();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction7;
                fragmentTransaction7 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle7 = new Bundle();
                if(vibor == true)
                    bundle7.putInt("Player", 1);
                else
                    bundle7.putInt("Player", 2);
                fragment_ranked_battles.setArguments(bundle7);
                fragmentTransaction7.commit();
                return fragment_ranked_battles;

            case 3:
                Fragment_texnika fragment_texnika = new Fragment_texnika();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4;
                fragmentTransaction4 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle4= new Bundle();
                bundle4.putBoolean("Player", vibor);
                fragment_texnika.setArguments(bundle4);
                fragmentTransaction4.commit();
                return fragment_texnika;

            case 4:

                Fragment_dostizenie fragment_dostizenie = new Fragment_dostizenie();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2;
                fragmentTransaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                bundle2.putBoolean("Player", vibor);
                bundle2.putBoolean("Result", false);
                fragment_dostizenie.setArguments(bundle2);
                fragmentTransaction2.commit();
                return fragment_dostizenie;


            case 5:
                Fragment_infografika fragment_infografika = new Fragment_infografika();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction6;
                fragmentTransaction6 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle6= new Bundle();
                bundle6.putBoolean("Player", vibor);
               // bundle6.putString("Player", playes_String);
                fragment_infografika.setArguments(bundle6);
                fragmentTransaction6.commit();
                return fragment_infografika;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return adapter_cvodka_dost[0];
            case 1:
                return adapter_cvodka_dost[1];
            case 2:
                return adapter_cvodka_dost[2];
            case 3:
                return adapter_cvodka_dost[3];
            case 4:
                return adapter_cvodka_dost[4];
            case 5:
                return adapter_cvodka_dost[5];

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 6;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: А что ваш код должен делать? Вы начинаете транзакцию и просто делаете `commit`, никуда не добавляя новый фрагмент. И аргументы надо сетить вне транзакции. Можно сразу после `new Fragment_ranked_battles();`

Comment: @eugeneek, скорее всего понял что вы имеете виду. Убрал транзакции и код работает на эмуляторе. Дело в том что оно и до этого работало на моем телефоне и эмуляторе. Приходили отчеты в основном на lenove и galaxy

Comment: отстранненый совет - почитайте конвенцию как оформлять код на джаве и конкретно под адроид. Все эти классы и имена переменных с нижними подчеркиваниями, if else без скобок и т.д. очень режут глаза и желание разбираться в вашем коде отпадает сразу. Вот ссылка : https://source.android.com/setup/code-style